# Cannot Delete an Object of One to Many Relationship Programmatically

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift-data

I'm building a SwiftUI app with SwiftData where the start page is a list of `Trip` objects and the `DetailView` will be a map with `Waypoint` objects that belong to that `Trip`. This is a one `Trip` to many `Waypoints` relationship. I have simplified the code below - the detail page is a list with a button to delete a `Waypoint`. In the real version, a user may tap on a `Waypoint` and choose to delete it.

My code (the `deleteOneWaypoint` func) breaks whenever the delete button is pushed just like in the real app when an annotation is tapped and selected for delete. Restarting the app shows that the `Waypoint` is indeed deleted even though the code broke. The error message is in the expanded `@Model` macro file at the line of the `Waypoint` sequence var. See the error at the end of this post. I have been unable to figure out how to fix this.

This code will run as is for testing (import both SwiftUI and SwiftData)

ContentView:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Query(sort: \.name, order: .forward) var trips: [Trip]

    @State private var selectedTrip: Trip?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List(selection: $selectedTrip) {
                ForEach(trips, id: \.self) { trip in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(trip.name)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete{ indexSet in
                    indexSet.forEach { index in
                        context.delete(trips[index])
                    }
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }//on delete
            }//list
            .navigationTitle("Trips")
            .padding()
        } detail: {
            //this ZStack seems to be needed to make iPad update correctly
            ZStack {
                if let selectedTrip {
                    DetailMapView(trip: selectedTrip)
                } else {
                    Text("Select a Trip")
                }
            }
        }//detail
        .onAppear {
            if trips.count == 0 {
                context.insert(Trip.exampleTrip1)
                context.insert(Trip.exampleTrip2)
            }
        }//on appear
    }//body

}//struct
```

DetailView:

```swift
struct DetailMapView: View {

    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    @Query(sort: \.name, order: .forward) var trips: [Trip]

    @State private var sequenceToDelete: Int = 100

    var trip: Trip

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(trip.name)
                if let waypoints = trip.waypoints {
                    List {
                        ForEach(waypoints, id: \.self) { wp in
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                Text("WP Sequence: \(wp.sequence)")
                                Text("WP Latitude: \(wp.latitude)")
                                Text("WP Longitude: \(wp.longitude)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Button(action: {
                    deleteOneWaypoint(seq: 1)
                }, label: {
                    Text("Delete WP with Sequence 1")
                })
        }//v
    }//body

    func deleteOneWaypoint(seq: Int) {
        let identity = trip.objectID
        //print("sequenceToDelete is \(sequenceToDelete)")
        //print("seq is \(seq)")
        if let waypoints = trip.waypoints {
        
            for w in 0..<waypoints.count {
                if waypoints[w].sequence == seq {
                    context.delete(waypoints[w])
                }
            }//for in
        
            var newWaypoints: [Waypoint] = []
        
            if let thisTrip: Trip = trips.first(where: { $0.objectID == identity} ) {
                if let tWaypoints = thisTrip.waypoints {
                    for wp in 0..<tWaypoints.count {
                        print("thisTrip[wp]sequence \(tWaypoints[wp].sequence)")
                    }
                    newWaypoints = tWaypoints
                }
            }//if let thisTrip
        
            for w in 0..<newWaypoints.count {
                print("newWaypoints[w].sequence is \(newWaypoints[w].sequence)")
            }
            for w in 0..<newWaypoints.count {
                if newWaypoints[w].sequence > seq {
                    newWaypoints[w].sequence = newWaypoints[w].sequence - 1
                }
            }//for in
        
            //should not need this:
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }//f
    }//delete one ...
}//struct
```

The Models:

```
@Model
final public class Trip: Identifiable {
    var name: String = "no name"

    @Relationship(.cascade) var waypoints: [Waypoint]?

    init(name: String, waypoints: [Waypoint]? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.waypoints = waypoints
    }

    static let exampleTrip1  = Trip(name: "San Jose to Vallejo", waypoints: [
        Waypoint(latitude: 37.338207, longitude: -121.886330, sequence: 0),
        Waypoint(latitude: 37.548271, longitude: -121.988571, sequence: 1),
        Waypoint(latitude: 38.1041, longitude: -122.2566, sequence: 2),
        Waypoint(latitude: 37.4419, longitude: -122.1430, sequence: 3)
    ])

    static let exampleTrip2  = Trip(name: "Palo Alto to Reno", waypoints: [
        Waypoint(latitude: 37.4419, longitude: -122.1430, sequence: 0),
        Waypoint(latitude: 38.5816, longitude: -121.4944, sequence: 1),
        Waypoint(latitude: 39.5296, longitude: -119.8138, sequence: 2)
    ])
   
}//trip model class

@Model
final public class Waypoint: Identifiable, Comparable {

    var latitude: Double = 0.0
    var longitude: Double = 0.0
    var sequence: Int = 0

    init(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, sequence: Int) {
        self.latitude = latitude
        self.longitude = longitude
        self.sequence = sequence
    }

    static let exampleWaypoint =
        Waypoint(latitude: 40.760780, longitude: -111.891045, sequence: 1)

    public static func <(lhs: Waypoint, rhs: Waypoint) -> Bool {
        lhs.sequence < rhs.sequence
    }

}//waypoint model
```

Error:

From expanded `var sequence`:

```
var sequence: Int = 0 @_PersistedProperty
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

{init(newValue) accesses (_$backingData) { self.setValue(for: \.sequence, to: newValue)
        } get {_$observationRegistrar.access(self, keyPath: \.sequence)
                    return self.getValue(for: \.sequence)//the ERROR is HERE
        
} set {_$observationRegistrar.withMutation(of: self, keyPath: \.sequence) {self.setValue(for: \.sequence, to: newValue)}
        }
}
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 15 beta 4, iOS 17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to explicitly remove the waypoint from the waypoints array as well as deleting it.
I am not sure if it is a bug or intended; I would have thought that the default behaviour of `nullify` on the inverse relationship would have taken care of this.

For convenience I modified your `Trip` so that `waypoints` wasn't an optional and has a default empty array and replaced your button with an `onDelete`:

```
struct DetailMapView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    @State private var sequenceToDelete: Int = 100
    
    var trip: Trip
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(trip.name)
            
            List {
                ForEach(trip.waypoints, id: \.self) { wp in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("WP Sequence: \(wp.sequence)")
                        Text("WP Latitude: \(wp.latitude)")
                        Text("WP Longitude: \(wp.longitude)")
                    }
                    
                }.onDelete{ indexSet in
                    indexSet.forEach { index in
                        let deletedWaypoint = self.trip.waypoints[index]
                        for waypoint in self.trip.waypoints {
                           if waypoint.sequence > deletedWaypoint.sequence {
                                waypoint.sequence -= 1
                            }
                        }
                        trip.waypoints.remove(at: index)
                        context.delete(deletedWaypoint)
                    }
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }//v
    }//body
}//struct
```

With some modifications you can have your waypoints sorted by sequence:

```
struct DetailMapView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    @State private var sequenceToDelete: Int = 100
    
    var trip: Trip
    
    var sortedWaypoints: [Waypoint] {
        return trip.waypoints.sorted { $0.sequence < $1.sequence }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(trip.name)
            
            List {
                ForEach(self.sortedWaypoints, id: \.self) { wp in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("WP Sequence: \(wp.sequence)")
                        Text("WP Latitude: \(wp.latitude)")
                        Text("WP Longitude: \(wp.longitude)")
                    }
                    
                }.onDelete{ indexSet in
                    indexSet.forEach { index in
                        let deletedWaypoint = self.sortedWaypoints[index]
                        var filteredWaypoints = [Waypoint]()
                        for waypoint in self.trip.waypoints {
                            if waypoint.sequence != deletedWaypoint.sequence {
                                filteredWaypoints.append(waypoint)
                            }
                            if waypoint.sequence > deletedWaypoint.sequence {
                                waypoint.sequence -= 1
                            }
                        }
                        context.delete(deletedWaypoint)
                        trip.waypoints = filteredWaypoints
                    }
                    do {
                        try context.save()
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
        }//v
    }//body
}//struct
```

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I'll need to work with this a bit. I cannot directly use the swipe to delete from .onDelete, because the list here is a simpler example than the app. In the app, the user will tap a map annotation and select from two actions - one of which is delete. Also, the only reason I made the waypoints optional was that I thought the WWDC sessions on SwiftData said that is required for a Relationship. I'll revisit. Your code works. I'll see if I can reconfigure to use a button.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to use a button; you would simply pass the `Waypoint` instance to the function and search through the `waypoints` array to find the waypoint with that sequence. Then the rest of my code stays the same.

Comment: I made it work with the button as described. I'm still struggling withe the real version that has the Waypoints on the map, but for this example all works as you described.